# Visual Studio Error on Source Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I tried to upgrade Visual Studio 2010 solution to a 2013/2015 version by manually editing the solution file and replacing

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010 to #Visual Studio 2015
```

Since then , I am unable to open the solution in VS 2010/2015. I know there's some issue with migration but the following error pops up when I try to open my solution in VS 2010
`he solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control.`
I have few pending changes on my projects which needs to be checked in. 
I am not sure if solution mentioned [here](https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/the-solution-appears-to-be-under-source-control-but-its-binding-information-cannot-be-found/#comments) is right for me.

I need a way to atleast open my solution in VS 2010 so I can check in and think of updating the VS version.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you undo your change and then open it in VS 2010?

Comment: Thats what I tried, but no luck. I see some difference in the paths for few projects on .sln file on server and on mine. Due to this, I cannot compile my solution. In a way, I am all screwed up..:(

Comment: In this case, I would either shelve my changes or copy them somewhere else, revert all the files, make sure I can build in VS, and then apply the changes one-by-one to see what was broke the build.

Comment: @Programmerzzz, did you check in changes made to that solution file? You can recreate a new workspace and get a specific version (use the changeset number just before check in the solution file) to get a usable version project.

Comment: No I didn't that's the problem I have to check in after I see changes that need the checkin then this happened

Comment: Create a new workspace and get the a worked version from TFS. And then compare the scc information under GlobalSection of the sln file with the broken one to see if the bind information in the broken sln file was changed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have VS2010 or VS 2015, so I created a blank solution in VS 2008 and made the following changes, it opened in VS 2013 without any issues:

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00 -> replaced that with 
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

Visual Studio 2008 -> replaced that with
Visual Studio 2013

Added a new line right after "# Visual Studio 2013": 
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
```

So in your case it would be something like (make sure to edit to the right version number)

```
Visual Studio 2015
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset developer environment using visual studio IDE. Command to run in command prompt is "devenv /resetuserdata"

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Either it's a solution, and should be an answer, or it's irrelevant, and shouldn't be a comment.